# Codigniter 3 и версии php

Tags: codeigniter

Ошибка:

```
Message: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated
```

Уже и php понижал до 5.4, все равно та же ошибка, хотя в документации CI пишут, что можно использовать 5.4 и выше. Ошибка возникает при попытке подключить класс. Пробовал в самом ядре найти строчку тип `$inst = & new Obj();` не нашел.

```
class Auth extends MY_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }   
}

require_once 'Auth.php';

class Admin extends Auth{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: Толку от понижения до 5.4? Ссылка в конструкторе была доступна в 4 версии. В версиях 5+ этот старый синтаксис недоступен.

Comment: И как в таком случае решить проблему?

Comment: Вы уверены, что у вас последняя версия Codigniter?

Comment: define('CI_VERSION', '3.0.3');

Comment: Странно, эта проблема вроде во 2 версии ещё была исправлена.

Comment: Если кто знает как решить проблему,просьба отписаться!